# get position of a textbox on my form in px

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to set the position of anew div box relative to the position of the comments box on my form. I can position the div but am struggling to get the value of the text box. I was thinking this would work but it doesn't

```
pos = document.getElementById('comments').style.top.value
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`pos = document.getElementById('comments').offsetTop`